# WPF app hang when scrolling on multi-line Textbox

Tags: wpf, scroll, datagrid, frameworks

I have a DataGrid in my window, one column contains CellingEditTemplate with a multi-line TextBox, this column in Database is not limited length, so users can input characters include Enter.

When the TextBox height over than app Screen Height, DataGrid scrollBar displayed, and then Scroll, app hang.

Exception Log:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value can not be null。
Parameter name: element
   At MS.Internal.Media.VisualTreeUtils.AsNonNullVisual(DependencyObject element, Visual&amp; visual, Visual3D&amp; visual3D)
   at System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(DependencyObject reference)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.FindScrollOffset(Visual v)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.OnAnchorOperation(Boolean isAnchorOperationPending)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.OnAnchorOperation()
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

It seems that this is caused by Framework, my framework version is 4.5.1

Here is 4.6.1 upgrade log:http://torrentilla.net/progs/sistem/4715-microsoft-net-framework-461-final-multi-ru.html

***103  +* Fixed an app hang case when scrolling [99716]***

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why are you allowing the textbox to size its height over that? You should use a fixed size textbox (or at least with maxheight), then let the textbox's scrollbarviewer handle it.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to control textbox height letter than grid height to keep all of the text show in one "ROW VIEW". 
But I still believe it is a framework issue.